# How can I check for "is not defined" eval(var) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There are lot of info to check for "undefined" normal vars in JavaScript, but I need to check for an eval(var) like:

```
var Hello_0 = "Hello 0 !";

console.log(" Hello_0 is: " + eval("Hello_"+0));

var dinamyc_var = "Hello_"+1;

//None of the next conditionals is triggered///
if (eval(dinamyc_var) === undefined) {
     console.log(" dinamyc_var is undefined ");
} 
if (eval(dinamyc_var) === null) {
     console.log(" dinamyc_var is null ");
}
if ( typeof eval(created_node) === undefined ) {
     console.log(" dinamyc_var is typeof undefined ");
}
if ( typeof eval(created_node) === null ) {
     console.log(" dinamyc_var is typeof null ");
}

console.log(" dinamyc_var is: " + eval(dinamyc_var));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mczdrv5t/

The console show the value of eval("Hello_"+0) because was declared, but the console show the next error when try to call  eval("Hello_"+1) that not was declared. I need to handle possible undeclared vars.

***Uncaught ReferenceError: Hello_1 is not defined
at eval (eval at ....***

Comment: In practice, you never need — or _want_, really — dynamic variable names. Use a simple object instead: `const obj = { Hello_0: "Hello 0 !" };` … `console.log(obj["Hello_" + 0]); console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty("Hello_" + 1));`, etc., or, for indexed structures, an array. See ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](/q/5187530/4642212). With `eval` and the necessary `try`–`catch` you only make everyone’s life unnecessarily hard, including your own.

Comment: [Off-topic]: `dinamyc` is actually spelled `dynamic`

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use eval.** If you need to store values of varying names, use an object instead:

```js
const values = {}

values["Hello_0"] = "Hello 0 !"

if (values["Hello_" + 1] === undefined) {
  // ...
}
```

As a sidenote, `if (eval('typeof ' + dynamic_var) === 'undefined')` would work but again, don't use eval.

Don't do `window[dynamic_var] = ...` to store global variables either, the names might clash with existing globals.

Comment: Thanks by the "typeof" eval suggestion!  I can`t use an object in my special case.

Comment: What's your special case? Are the variables already defined in global scope by someone else? in that case, `window[varname] == undefined` would still be cleaner.